# Generate sequence number in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have a source xml file as below:

```
<transactions>
<transaction>
    <number>12</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>12</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>13</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>13</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
</transaction>
</transactions>
```

Want to generate the response using XSLT. Would like to generate the `<line>` element based on `<number>` element. For example: For every same `<number>` would like to generate the sequence number. The target file must be generated like below:

```
<transactions>
<transaction>
    <number>12</number>
    <line>1</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>12</number>
    <line>2</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>13</number>
    <line>1</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>13</number>
    <line>2</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
    <line>1</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
    <line>2</line>
</transaction>
<transaction>
    <number>14</number>
    <line>3</line>
</transaction>
</transactions>
```

Comment: Good question!  A really short and simple XSLT 1.0 solution exists.

Answer (score 1):

Group the `transaction` elements by `number` with `for-each-group`, then push `current-group()` through `apply-templates` and then in the template for `transaction` you can populate the `line` element using the value of `position()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="transactions">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="transaction" group-by="number">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="transaction">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
          <line>
              <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </line>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjm

The above would group `transaction` elements with the same `number` value together in the result, if that is not wanted then in XSLT 3 another option would be to use an accumulator to keep a record of `transaction` elements by `number` value and output the accumulator value in the template for `transaction`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="trans-count"/>

  <xsl:accumulator name="trans-count" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer)" initial-value="map{}">
      <xsl:accumulator-rule match="transaction"
        select="let $number := xs:integer(number)
                return if (map:contains($value, $number))
                       then map:put($value, $number, $value($number) + 1)
                       else map:put($value, $number, 1)"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:template match="transaction">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
          <line>
              <xsl:value-of select="accumulator-before('trans-count')(xs:integer(number))"/>
          </line>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjm/1

Both full examples use the XSLT 3 way of `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` to declare the identity transformation as the base of the transformation, for an XSLT 2 processor you need to spell it out as

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

instead.

For an XSLT 1 solution using keys and Muenchian grouping you can use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="trans-group"
    match="transaction" use="number"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
       <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="transactions">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each select="transaction[generate-id() = generate-id(key('trans-group', number)[1])]">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('trans-group', number)"/>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="transaction">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
          <line>
              <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
          </line>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYjm/4

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using xslt2.0 and in 2.0 current-group() function doesn't exist.

Comment: XSLT 2 was introduced in 2007 and it does support `xsl:for-each-group` as well as the `current-group` function. So not sure why you claim you use XSLT 2 but don't have support for that function. XSLT 2 is supported by processors like Saxon 9, XmlPrime, AltovaXML.

Comment: Hi Martin, I'm using oracle ICS which uses xslt2.0 that's the reason, I want a solution compatible to xslt 2.0

Comment: As I said, for me XSLT 2 is what the W3C specified in 2007 and that spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#current-group does define the function I have used. If you use a processor that doesn't support it then I wouldn't call it an XSLT 2 processor. In the Java world Saxon 9 is available for XSLT 2 or 3. Not sure how that fits into your environment but that is a different issue. If you need an XSLT 1 solution or an XSLT solution for a particular processor then retag and reword your question appropriately.

Comment: I have added an XSLT 1 sample using keys and Muechian grouping that should give the same result as the XSLT 2/3 approach that used `for-each-group` and `current-group()`.

Comment: Martin, to transform the provided XML document into the wanted result, no grouping is necessary.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, I didn't say grouping is necessary, I just made a suggestion to use `for-each-group` to try to solve it, given that the question was tagged as [tag:xslt-2.0]. Then the poster made all sorts of wrong claims about `current-group` not being supported in XSLT 2 or my suggestion not being compatible with XSLT 2. Then I also provided an XSLT 1 transliteration of my suggestion using grouping.

Answer (score 0):

**This is a short and simple XSLT 1.0 solution -- just 15 lines** (works with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0 processors because XSLT is backwards-compatible):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="number">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <line><xsl:value-of select="count(../preceding-sibling::*[number = current()]) + 1"/></line>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <number>12</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>12</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>13</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>13</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>14</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>14</number>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <number>14</number>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<transactions>
   <transaction>
      <number>12</number>
      <line>1</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>12</number>
      <line>2</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>13</number>
      <line>1</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>13</number>
      <line>2</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>14</number>
      <line>1</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>14</number>
      <line>2</line>
   </transaction>
   <transaction>
      <number>14</number>
      <line>3</line>
   </transaction>
</transactions>
```